# React router: catch a login-success url with a token being passed then redirect to homepage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm writing a React App that has token based authorisation: external auth. service redirects the user to the App with a token being passed in the url like this: `/login-success/?token=<token>`.

In the App I need to capture that token and store in the state. My idea of doing this as follows:

1) Create a `LoginSuccess` component:

```
    class LoginSuccess extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        const {
          actions: { setToken, redirectToHomepage },
          location: { query }
        } = this.props

        setToken(query.token)
        redirectToHomepage()
      }
    }
```

2) Redux-connect the actions (in a container): `setToken` & `redirectToHomepage`

3) Add a child route `<Route path="/login-success" component={LoginSuccess} />`

My question is: Is there a nicer/simpler way of doing this?

**a small update**: I might be using `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: Your goal is only to remove `?token` from url ?

Comment: Yes, and also to store it into the redux store.

Comment: I think that the best way is to store this in cookies, this can be handle by the server with the : `setCookie` header. It is strange to do this in the frontend, why you need this token in your redux-store ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, might be better storing it in the cookie - I thought the token is part of the application state. Anyway, the example above fortunately decouples the logic behind `setToken`. In order to set token from a query string is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good way to do this client-side

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for when you mean a simple way of capturing the token from the query param:

I usually use URL structures like: `/login-success/<token>` then in the routes, I use: `<Route path="/login-success/:token" component={LoginSuccess} />`

Then, when I `mapStateToProps` I just do:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
       token: ownProps.token
   };
};
```

Now token just becomes accessible in the `this.props` object.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not exactly what I was looking for. This is just some part of it. I was wondering if theres a solution that does not require me to create a Component at all...

Comment: Ah. You mean you just want to capture it in your state object and not use it in a component? What about ``onEnter`` on the ``Route`` component, setting the state, and then redirecting via ``replace``? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback